# Need a way to extract headings content without using regEx

Tags: c#, selenium, html-agility-pack

I've seen that the html agility pack can come handy but I dont understand how it works. This is how I got the code right now and at the moment it extracts the headings content successfully but also takes more unneeded content.

```
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(response);

    String sourcePage = driver.PageSource;
    Regex regexHeadings = new Regex("(?<=\\>)(?!\\<)(.*)(?=\\<)(?<!\\>)");
    foreach (Match match in regexHeadings.Matches(sourcePage))
    {
        h1Keywords.Add(match.Value);
        colorOutput(ConsoleColor.White, match.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you using HtmlAgility Pack with the help of XPath / CSS Selectors.
See this cheatsheet for help: https://devhints.io/xpath

Quick example:

```
var url = "https://devhints.io/xpath";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);

foreach (var heading in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(heading.InnerText);
}
```